Google Speech-to-Text API Misses Majority of Words in Audio Transcription
I am using google speech to text service. Since the audios In my project are longer then 60 sec I use longRunningRecognize function. I run my tests on mp3 and wav format song files expecting to get all the lyrics of songs. The results I get are partial often less then 30% of lyrics.
From optimize audio files I tried to do some optimizations with file. Here is how my files ffprobe looks
Input #0, flac, from 'h.flac':
  Metadata:
    comment         : 
    title           : Charlotte Cardin-dirty dirty (lyrics)
    encoded_by      : 
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Duration: 00:03:20.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 165 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 16000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s16

After getting lyrics from results I have ~300 symbols while the original lyrics has 1400 symbols.
And here are my configs sent to api
 {
    encoding: 'FLAC',
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode: 'en-US',
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
 }

Is there any other optimizations I can do to get all the lyrics

Hi Armen ,  you can try using enableWordTimeOffsets : false  OR
to get all the Lyrics for longer audios more than 60 sec, you can refer to this doc once Transcribe long audio files into text  .Let me know if this helps or not .

Thx Sourav. I'm already using async functionality for long audio files and I have added "enableWordTimeOffsets" parameter, and it didn't change anything. Any other ideas to try?

Hi , It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case . Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
